# How to select, inside a df, only columns that have numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

i have multiple columns and want to see inside them what are the null values. then i want to know if columns that have null values are numeric

df.isnull().sum() -> gives me the sum of null values inside the df (question 2 - in pandas the result are only the top 5 and last 5 colums; How can i see all columns? )
then from the result given i wanted to get only columns with numeric values

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) that would help us help you. :)

Comment: BTW, check out the [tour], and if you want more tips, [ask].

Answer (score 0):

1st, you can type 'df.info()'
There is about null data and amount of index.

If it is small data,
you can check like this

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        if df.isna().iloc[i][j] == True:
            print(f'index is {i}, column is {df.columns[j]}')
```

but if it is big data, it can be make a problem.
if you wanna check this on other dataframe,
you can save it.

```
df_null = {'index':[], 'columns':[]}
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        if df.isna().iloc[i][j] == True:
            df_null['index'].append(i)
            df_null['columns'].append(df.columns[j])

dfna = pd.DataFrame(df_null)
```

It's working. but it is so slow.
maybe there is more good answer but
I know only this way.
then, good day!
I hope this answer helps you